# How do I install a custom kernel on a google compute engine instance?

Tags: linux-kernel, google-compute-engine, grub2

I would like to install a custom kernel image on a Google Compute Engine instance.  I have an instance running with:

```
foo@instance-1:/boot/efi$ uname -a
Linux instance-1 4.10.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 22 17:43:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I've built and installed my kernel image:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.10.0-rc8.10.0-rc8_amd64.deb
```

It shows up in the grub configuration file, I've set the default grub menu item to correct number, and I've run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Yet, when I reboot, I get the same kernel I started with.

Google documentation on this seems to be non-existent.  There is one spot that suggests I might have to create the image externally, install the kernel, and import it.  However, I will need to do this a lot, so I'd rather just install new kernels the old fashioned way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that in Google's stock Ubuntu image, there's a grub config file:

```
/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg
```

that overrides what's in

```
/etc/default/grub
```

Editing the first file got everything working.

Comment: tip for search engines: this also works to add additional linux kernel boot parameters to gcp instances

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting this, I assume you have a fallback option? Some way of falling back to your current state. This is important because it seems you may not have physical access to the system.

Please check what `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` shows as default kernel. It will be a section *beginning* with `menuentry` and under that, an entry starting with `linux`. If that points to `/boot/<default-kernel>` then that's what you need to update along with `initrd` entry so that both kernel image and initramfs point to your custom kernel.

Also, it's possible that boot order of kernel images is alphabetical so newer kernel images (later in alphabetical order) have preference over older ones. In that case if you can change kernel image's file name to be higher than default kernel image, and same for the corresponding initramfs and config files (they will all be similarly named) and then run `update-grub` that may be quicker way of booting into your custom kernel. You can find those files under `/boot/`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going into `/boot/` and removing the old images and then running `sudo dpkg -i <new_image>` and rebooting the system with `sudo reboot`