# Google compute engine reboot into newly built kernel

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I'm building a linux kernel in an instance of a google compute engine VM as part of a homework assignment. How can I alter the configuration of the VM so that when I reboot I will boot into the newly built kernel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a custom kernel on a google compute engine instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426549/how-do-i-install-a-custom-kernel-on-a-google-compute-engine-instance)

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for the resource, when I finish building the modules I will try the recommended steps.

Comment: Well, I finished building the kernel after running sudo make modules, and did a reboot. The VM automatically booted into the new kernel I built. I assume something in /boot/ was changed for me, so yay!

Answer (score 1):

Finished building the kernel after `sudo make modules` with:

```
   sudo make -j 4
   sudo make modules_install
   sudo make install
   sudo reboot
```

VM booted into the new kernel.